# Table w/MYSQL "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Tags: android, mysql, database, android-studio, row

I´m making a table on Android Studio that fetch info from a MYSQL database, it should return 2 rows, but instead it returns this error code. I need it to be able to automatically create rows depending on the number of rows i get from the db.

Help please!

This is the code from the table xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/table"
    tools:context=".foliosMonitor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp"
    >

    <TableRow

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:background="#205FA1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ticketIdName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="TicketId" />





        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/truckplatesName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="TruckPlates" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ecoTruckName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="EcoTruck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statusName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Status" />







    </TableRow>

    <TableRow

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#D8D8D8">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ticketId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
            android:text="TicketId"
            android:onClick="editTabla"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/truckplates"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
            android:text="TruckPlates"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ecoTruck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
            android:text="EcoTruck"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Status" />



    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

This is the void that creates the table on the activity

```
public void readTable(){
    
            View registro = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.table_row_monitor, null, false);
            String URLFETCHTABLE = "https://www.cedepaser.com.mx/TruckParking/App/php/getTicketTable.php?customerId=" + customerId;
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    URLFETCHTABLE,
                    null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("ticket");
                        for(int i = 0; i<=jsonArray.length() - 1; i++){
    
                            Log.d("valueOfI", String.valueOf(i));
                            Log.d("ARRAYLENGTH", String.valueOf(jsonArray.length()));
    
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            TextView ticketId = registro.findViewById(R.id.ticketId);
                            TextView truckPlates = registro.findViewById(R.id.truckplates);
                            TextView ecoTruck = registro.findViewById(R.id.ecoTruck);
                            TextView status = registro.findViewById(R.id.status);
    
                            ticketId.setText(jsonObject.getString("ticketId"));
                            truckPlates.setText(jsonObject.getString("truckPlates"));
                            ecoTruck.setText(jsonObject.getString("ecoTruck"));
                            status.setText(jsonObject.getString("idStatus"));
                            tbUsuarios.addView(registro);
    
                            iCount = i;
                        }
                        Log.d("iCount", String.valueOf(iCount));
    
    
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("ARRAYLENGTH", "ENTRO AL CATCH");
    
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-add same "registro" View to "tbUsuarios". I don't know what is "tbUsuarios" but it seems a ViewGroup (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ConstraintLayout, FrameLayout, etc...) and if you add "registro" at first FOR-loop-cycle, you cannot re-add same "registro" because it is already assigned to a parent.

I suppose you don't want to re-add SAME "registro", so I suppose you have just to move:

```
View registro = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.table_row_monitor, null, false);
```

at the beginning of FOR-loop.